# Regarding Lookup Filters in salesforce

Tags: custom-field, customsetting

**what is the use of lookup filter in salesforce? when we will use lookup filter for object creation or custom Field creation, what the Lookup filter settings do in Salesforce? Anyone Share the Answer?**

Answer (score 1):

A brief google search turned up [an answer from help.salesforce.com](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=fields_lookup_filters.htm&language=en)

A brief excerpt from that page:

> Lookup filters are administrator settings that restrict the valid values and lookup dialog results for lookup, master-detail, and hierarchical relationship fields.

Another way you can think of it is like a validation rule that's specifically for lookup, master-detail, and hierarchical relationship fields.

My company, for example, has a lookup filter to ensure that Opportunities are not related to Accounts with a record type of `Parent`.

Answer (score 0):

**What is a Lookup Filter?**

A lookup filter limits which records can be associated within an object relationship.

**Why use Lookup Filters?**

Use lookup filters to enforce data quality and increase usability within object relationships.

**Record Types in Lookup Filters**
If the value of a relationship field should only consist of records with a particular record type, specify the record type in a lookup filter.

**For example**, if the Account Name field on opportunities should only have accounts with a Customer Account custom record type, define the following lookup filter to restrict users to only creating or editing opportunities associated with accounts that have a Customer Account record type, excluding accounts with Partner Account and Competitor Account record types:

**Filter Criteria**
Account Name: Account Record Type equals value Customer Account

**Custom Error Message**
Account does not exist or is not a customer account.

**Lookup Window Text**
You can only associate customer accounts to an opportunity. Search results only display customer accounts.

Also see this helpful [link](https://certifiedondemand.com/salesforce-filtered-relationships/) for Lookup Filter

See [More examples](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=fields_lookup_filters_examples.htm)